# What does $json->SearchResponse->Errors mean in this code?

Tags: php, json

```
$body = file_get_contents($url);   //defined somewhere else

$json = json_decode($body);
if(isset($json->SearchResponse->Errors)) 
    throw new Exception ("search Error");
```

What does `$json->SearchResponse->Errors` refer to? I mean does this look into the contents of body (or) searchresponse and errors are objects..?

Comment: Try this in google: `php json_decode`

Comment: http://uk.php.net/json_decode

Comment: I know wht json_decode does.. i am asking for json->searchResponse->Errors ??

Comment: I'm sure looking at the spec which we pointed you to would have explained fully what it was you were looking for.  You obviously don't know what json decode does, or at least don't understand it fully.

Answer (score 2):

It searches in the response submitted by `$body` for the respective entries `SearchResponse` and below that `Errors`.

If it finds any object (which probably indicates, that an error happened while processing the request), it transforms this error to a PHP Exception, which may be caught by using `try catch` somewhere else in the code.

A JSON response, that might trigger this behaviour could look like this

```
{ 
  "SearchResponse": {
    "Error": "Something went wrong here!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes they are. If you use `json_decode()` without the parameter for an associative array, it will return an object. This is what you have here.

Comment: @NarenKarthik Just accept an answer after 15mins, so others see that this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In the object serialized to JSON, there was an object named `SearchResponse`, which has a property named `Errors`. If the second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://uk.php.net/json_decode) is false (which is the default), `{}` will be unserialized into `stdClass` Objects (true would make associative arrays).

So the JSON could have been something like:

```
{
    "SearchResponse" : {
        "Errors" : 1
    }
}
```